# returning data from a parent controller method after a callback function has completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, adonis.js

I know similar questions have been asked and I have tried to understand them and apply to my own issue, but I have not yet been able to make anything work.

The following code is a function in an Adonis.js controller.

It is supposed to take a search term and use a Google search API (serpApi) to search the term and then return an array of URLs.

However, at the moment I can only get it to console.log the 'links' but I want to return an array of links whenever the function 'googleSearch' is called.

```
     async googleSearch(searchTerm) {

        let client = new GSR.GoogleSearchResults("[MyApiKey]")

            var parameter = {
                q: `${searchTerm}`,
                hl: "en",
                gl: "us",
                google_domain: "google.com",
            };

            const callback = function(data) {
                let links = []; 
                for (let i = 0; i < data.organic_results.length; i++) {                       
                    links.push(data.organic_results[i].link)            
                }
              console.log(links)                                  
           }            

        client.json(parameter, callback)

        }
```

I can see the data I need when I console log from within the callback function, however, I want to return this data when the parent function is called, not log it to the console.

I know the problem lies somewhere in the asynchronous/synchronous area and I have tried to figure things out reorganizing the callback and changing the order of things as best I know how but I can't seem to get it to work.

Below is an example of what I am trying to make happen, obviously it does not work but perhaps it helps to clarify things.

```
    async googleSearch(searchTerm) {

        let results= []
        let client = new GSR.GoogleSearchResults("[MyApiKey]")

            var parameter = {
                q: `${searchTerm}`,
                hl: "en",
                gl: "us",
                google_domain: "google.com",
            };

            const callback = await function(data) {
                let links = []; 
                for (let i = 0; i < data.organic_results.length; i++) {                       
                    links.push(data.organic_results[i].link)            
                }
              results.push(links)                                
           }            

        client.json(parameter, callback)
       return results 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1.

Try to shift from the mindset of "waiting until", better think of it like "tell me when you are done".

Imagine your method googleSearch with a second parameter that would be a function provided by your parent (calling) component. This function would be invoked within the current callback just instead of the console.log(links). In this way the calling component will not wait until receive the result with the links, but the parent component will receive the asynchronous call of provided function when the links are ready, they will be passed as a parameter. So let's call that function 'processLinks'.

```
googleSearch(searchTerm, processLinks) {

    let client = new GSR.GoogleSearchResults("[MyApiKey]")

        var parameter = {
            q: `${searchTerm}`,
            hl: "en",
            gl: "us",
            google_domain: "google.com",
        };

        const callback = function(data) {
            let links = []; 
            for (let i = 0; i < data.organic_results.length; i++) {                       
                links.push(data.organic_results[i].link)            
            }
          processLinks(links)                                  
       }            

    client.json(parameter, callback)

    }
```

Then the parent component will call something like:

```
onSearchTermChange(searchTerm){
  childComponent.googleSearch(searchTerm, this.processLinks);
},
processLinks(links){
  // Do whatever needed with the links.
}
```

Variant 2.

Upper solution is kind of implementing an own promise mechanism (not so cool, just to help you understand the principles). So the second variant, instead of adding a processLinks function as a parameter, make googleSearch to return a promise. The constructor of the Promise accepts resolve and reject methods as a lambda parameters (they will be used again as a callbacks, but instead of declaring them as a function in your parent component, they are part of the Promise. You can use the resolve to pass the data back to the parent component and use reject if something goes wrong and the parent should not wait for the result anymore. Let try it with an example:

```
    googleSearch(searchTerm) {
      return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
         let client = new GSR.GoogleSearchResults("[MyApiKey]")

           var parameter = {
              q: `${searchTerm}`,
              hl: "en",
              gl: "us",
              google_domain: "google.com",
          };

          const callback = function(data) {
              let links = []; 
              for (let i = 0; i < data.organic_results.length; i++) {                       
                  links.push(data.organic_results[i].link)            
              }
              resolve(links)                                  
          }            

         client.json(parameter, callback) // TODO If this fails call reject(errorDetails);
      }); // The promise returned.     
    }
```

Then the parent service would use the returned promise to specify what to do when the promise is resolved. This is done calling 'then' and passing two lambdas (one for succsessful scenario, one for the error handling)

```
onSearchTermChange(searchTerm){
  childComponent.googleSearch(searchTerm, this.processLinks).then((links) => {
      // Here we are when the child component invoked 'resolve(links)'
    }, (error) => {
      // Well in upper example I dont use the error handled (and should). You can add it for example if your call to client.json fails for some reason.
    });
},
```

Did I explain to you what you needed or the two variants actually confused you more? :) Please, let me know.